# Ask for access to Userinformation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm creating an App under Windows 8.1 for our Company. Within this app I Need Access to the Userinformation:

```
await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
await UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync();
await UserInformation.GetFirstNameAsync();
await UserInformation.GetLastNameAsync();
await UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync();
```

For this to work, the user has to have his Settings correct: Change PC Settings -> Privacy -> Allow Access Let apps Access my Name, pciture, and other account info

How can I ask for this permission in Code or make my app trusted, so I always get Access to the Userinformation? Is that in anyway possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't ask for this permission in code. Those methods will return an empty string, if access is blocked .

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getprincipalnameasync.aspx) :

> "Access to the display name can be blocked by privacy settings (for
>   example, if the UserInformation::NameAccessAllowed property is false).
>   If access is blocked, this method returns an empty string. "

Comment: Is there a way to allow Access through Group Policys or certificates or something like that?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this, instead you can ask the user by popup to go PC Settings -> Privacy -> Allow Access Let apps Access my Name, pciture, and other account info. so the user can using your app, if he allowed this option .